# Core Data - fetch object with keypath and Object ID

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, core-data

I would like to fetch my data from Core Data, where the books assigned to the person "Max". For this, I have the following code:

```
  let request = NSFetchRequest<Book>(entityName: "Book")
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "person.firstName = %@", "Max")
    do {
       let books = try context.fetch(request)
       for x in 0 ..< books.count {
          print(books[x].name)
       }
    } catch { }
```

But now I would like to fetch the data where the books are assigned to a person with the Object ID "xyz".

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "person.self = %@", myPersonObjectID)
```

Comment: Your question title does not match the question body (which not about *sorting* at all).

Comment: I updated it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the object with `existingObject` from the Object ID and use that in the predicate.

```
if let myPerson = context.existingObject(with: myPersonObjectID) {
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "person = %@", myPerson)
}
```

Comment: It's usually better to use `existingObject(with:)`, which will return nil if there's no object with the ID.

Comment: @TomHarrington Thanks! Updated my answer.